# How could I make my prime generator function faster

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

to gain hands-on experience, I'm trying to solve the problems in [spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) . The problem in the link asks to find all prime numbers between given 2 numbers. So how I implement this with python 2.7

```
# printing all prime numbers between given two inputs
import math
def findPrimes(num1,num2):
    for num in range(num1,num2+1):
        isPrime=True
        for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
            if num%i==0:
                isPrime=False
                break
        if isPrime:
            print num


def main():
    inputs=[]
    numOfTestCases=int(raw_input())

    while(numOfTestCases>0):
        line=raw_input()
        numbers=line.split()
        inputs.append(numbers)
        numOfTestCases-=1

    for testCase in inputs:
        findPrimes(int(testCase[0]),int(testCase[1]))
        print ""

main()
```

However, when I send the code, I get time-exceed limit. How could I make my code fast enough?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  Assuming you aren't producing huge primes, it should be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: @NathanMerrill actually, there are really huge numbers in the test cases

Comment: This is more of a maths algorithm questions than code - there are a number of known solutions algorithmically to this with differing complexities.

Comment: use the sieve of eratosthenes, and I'd say hard code prime numbers upto some  number to make it faster still. also choose `pypy` as compiler if it's there

Comment: @Andrew, although I agree with you, I also think that, the question contains an algorithmic point of view even if it is related with math

Comment: @zwlayer Just looked at the question, it has a tag indicating Sieve of Eratosthenes.  It's definitely the algorithm you want.

Comment: @zwlayer - the maths stack exchange site would be more suitable in effect.

Comment: @NathanMerrill thank you for the hint. This is my first time at Spoj, so I couldnt see that tag.

Comment: http://thelivingpearl.com/2013/01/06/how-to-find-prime-numbers-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Prime_Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and it is quite simple. First you initialize all numbers to be prime. Then for each prime you remove its multiples from the prime list. And it's time complexity is near liner `O(nloglogn)`. Something like this:

```
N = 1000
is_prime = [1]*N
for i in xrange(2,N):
    if is_prime[i]:
        for j in xrange(2*i,N,i):
            is_prime[j] = 0
```

This implementation should do just fine. But there are some extra optimizations that you can find them in the link above.
*Note that `0` and `1` are not prime.*

Answer (score 0):

No, the numbers aren't huge in spoj/PRIME1. The sieve of Eratosthenes works extremely well there, but even trial division  gets you through there, if you test by primes, and test odds only (or better, only 6-coprimes or 30-coprimes).

You need only find primes below the square root of your top limit, in advance. `sqrt(10^9)` is about 32,000, so there are only about 3,400 primes  to maintain. That's nothing.

---

*6-coprimes*: numbers coprime with 6, i.e. with 2 and 3, so there's no need to test divide them by 2 nor 3, when testing for primes. You need to find a way to generate them directly, so there won't be any multiples of 2 and 3 among the numbers you need to test, *by construction*.

Comment: something still not clear? do ask. otherwise, please mark as accepted the one answer that was most helpful to you. :)